# NotFileFound when writing Exif data for image description; reading is fine

Tags: java, android, exif

This is how I read exif data, it works fine:

```
InputStream in;
        String description;
        try{
            in=getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
            ExifInterface exifInterface=new ExifInterface(in);
            description=exifInterface.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_IMAGE_DESCRIPTION);
            exif.setText(description);
        }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }//catch
```

This is how I write it, but it throws FileNotFoundException at the line containing ExifInterface constructor:

```
public boolean onEditorAction(TextView textView, int actionId, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
    boolean handled=false;
    if(actionId== EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEND){
        String decription=input.getText().toString();
        try {
            input.setText("");
            File file=new File(uri.toString());
            ExifInterface exifInterface=new ExifInterface(file.getCanonicalPath());
            exifInterface.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_IMAGE_DESCRIPTION, decription);
            exifInterface.saveAttributes();
            exif.setText(decription);
        }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch(NullPointerException e){
            Toast.makeText(this,"Select a photo first!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        handled=true;
    }
    return handled;
}
```

I tried Uri.getPath(). It throws the same error.

**EDIT**

I added the write permission (I don't know how to make the pop up dialog):

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="zoom2.david.com.exif">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
    android:maxSdkVersion="18"/>
<application...
```

Here is the url and path:
[image]

Here is the error message when debugging:

[image]

**EDIT2**

I want to further explain my problem because I still haven't found any answer to it yet. I hope someone can help me out. So this uri that I use to get the file from is obtained when the user picks an photo. I tried to construct exifInterface like:`new ExifInterface(file.get.getAbsolutePath())`. Still, the same error.

Comment: Are you sure you're passing a `file://` uri and have READ / WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission?

Comment: `File file=new File(uri.toString());`. That will not work as you have seen. You should write to the uri in the same way you readed from it. Well if you have a write permission.